# Why is the form opacity not changing?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I was just experimenting with windows forms and came across the property `Opacity`. I made a very simple program containing a form with a textbox and added the following code:-

```
   this.textBox1.MouseHover += ChangeOpacity ; 
   private void ChangeOpacity(object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
      this.Opacity = 50 ; 
      this.Refresh() ; 
   }
```

I want to change the opacity of the the form to 50% when the user hovers it's mouse over the textbox, but this code is not working. The opacity still remains at 100%. Can anyone point out the mistake I am doing in the above code, or what should I do to correct my problem. I also tried using `Invalidate()` ans then `Update()` but it is still not changing the opacity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Opacity` would be in percentage. The default would be `1.00`

Try putting:

```
this.Opacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 2):

Opacity goes in the values from 0 to 1

so 100 % would be a 1 and 50 % would be a .5 and 0% would be a 0.

try with it

```
this.Opacity=.5;
```