# MouseDown making something transparent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make it so that when you hold your mouse down it will make the form transparent and when you take your mouse off it will make it go back to normal.

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                Form1.ActiveForm.Opacity = 90;
        }
```

Comment: Yeah, so what are you asking? What problem are you facing? How can we help?

Comment: The `Opacity` property has a range between 0 and 1. So, you probably want `.Opacity = 0.9;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the form opacity not changing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627865/why-is-the-form-opacity-not-changing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fairly complete sample of what you're trying to do. Does it help?

```
void Main()
{
    var f = new Form1();
    f.ShowDialog();
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        this.MouseDown += (s, e) => this.Opacity = 0.2;
        this.MouseUp += (s, e) => this.Opacity = 1.0;
    }
}
```

It may help you to read the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.opacity?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Percentages are always to be read as the number divided by `100.0`. So if you want `20%` then you need `0.2`.